# Mysql - select several rows with same value

Tags: php, mysql, select, rows

I've got a table called 'data', and some columns:
user,unit,price,discount,description.

```
 -----   -----  ------  ---------   ----------- 
| user | unit |  price | discount | description |
 -----   -----  ------  ---------   -----------
| test | unit |  100   |    50    |     des     |
-----   -----  -------   --------   -----------
| test2| unit2 |  200  |    20    |     des     |
 -----   -----  -----    --------   -----------
```

```
<?php 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
 $id  = $_GET['id'];
 require_once('dbConnect.php');
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE description='".$id."'";
 $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 $res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
 $result = array();
 array_push($result,array(
     "user"=>$res['user'],
     "unit"=>$res['unit'],
     "price"=>$res['price'],
     "discount"=>$res['discount']
 )
 );
 echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
 mysqli_close($con);
 }
```

From this code, I get:

```
{"result":[{"user":"test","unit":"unit","price":"100","discount":"50"}]}
```

so it's just the first row. I want to get both of them like this:

```
{"result":[{"user":"test","unit":"unit","price":"100","discount":"50"}]}
{"result2":[{"user":"test2","unit":"unit2","price":"200","discount":"20"}]}
```

so there will be 2 arrays.

Comment: Warning: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to learn more on how to prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write a loop containing calls of `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.  As you iterate, store the rows of data.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
    array_push($result, array(
         "user" => $row['user'],
         "unit" => $row['unit'],
         "price" => $row['price'],
         "discount" => $row['discount']
         )
     );
}
```

Or if you replace the `*` in your `SELECT` clause to nominate your desired rows, you can use the top-voted comment on the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` manual page...

```
for ($result = []; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r); $result[] = $row);
```

This compact one-liner will convert your resultset into a multidimensional array with the same structure as the previous code block without the iterated `array_push()` function calls.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given in /storage/h7/538/1215538/public_html/UserLogin.php on line 9
{"result":[]}

Comment: @NikitaIvanov  I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
 $id  = $_GET['id'];
 require_once('dbConnect.php');
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE description='".$id."'";
 $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 $result = array();
 while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
    $aRaw["user"] = $res['user'];
    $aRaw["unit"] = $res['unit'];
    $aRaw["price"] = $res['price'];
    $aRaw["discount"] = $res['discount'];
    $result[] = $aRaw;
 }
 );
 echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
 mysqli_close($con);
 }
```

**Warning**: code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks

Comment: @Pang we talking regarding get all records not about how to handle SQL Injection and thats work with her, obviously  she new  in that, so don't make things complicated.

Answer (score 0):

first of all your query is open to sql injection you should use [mysqli preprared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

so then your code would look something like this

**Edit:** my original answer was incomplete as i didn't test it below is my corrected answer

```
<?php 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
 $id  = $_GET['id'];
 require_once('dbConnect.php');
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE description=?";
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);
 $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
 $stmt->execute(); //originally I combined this and next line, it was incorrect
 if ($result = $stmt->get_result()){
    //originally I used wrong method below
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $myArray[] = $row;
    }
    //uncomment below if you're sending response as json responese
    //header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($myArray);
}

$result->close();
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean in /storage/h7/538/1215538/public_html/UserLogin.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /storage/h7/538/1215538/public_html/UserLogin.php on line 11

Comment: I've updated my answer, I apologize I posted it incorrectly originally